# register custom user with django allauth

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I have a custom User model:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=False, null=False) # validators should be a list
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number', 'email']

    objects = UserManager()
```

With his UserManager:

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, phone_number, password):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a phone_number')

        user = self.model(
            username,
            phone_number,
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, phone_number, password):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a phone_number')

        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            phone_number,
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

I am using allauth to register users, but when I register a new user in /rest-auth/registration (POST) the fields a still the default ones (username, email, password1, password2) instead of adding phone_number for example. How can I do to allow more (or delete some) fields to register a new user?

**=== EDIT ===**

I also have In my settings.py

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userTest.User'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'userTest.forms.RegisterForm'
```

and in forms.py a form just for testing but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number', max_length=17)
    first_name = forms.CharField()

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend AbstaractBaseUser

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager)

    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
        phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=False, null=False) # validators should be a list
        email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
        points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number', 'email']

        objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: But AbstractBaseUser is a superclass of AbstractUser, so it just have less fields. Does it makes a diference anyway?  PS: Look at my edited question, maybe you know something about the things I added